# couldn't display osascript dialog with crontab

Tags: cron, applescript

How can I display osascript dialog with crontab?  I could simply execute `"""osascript -e 'display dialog "displaying content" ' """` with python `os.system` in terminal, and the dialog bar will show, which means the `os.system` properly executed the `osascript command`. and I can execute the crontab command like `32 10 * * *  mkdir /path` to create a folder at 10:32am, which means the crontab works well too. However, when I execute `"""osascript -e 'display dialog "displaying content" ' """` with crontab, nothing show up, seems something block the dialog bar from showing on my screen, I wanna know what happened?

Comment: I'm just happy someone else out there uses display dialog with crontab. It's great for reminding you to do daily/weekly things and keeping your mental load light. Power of Habit.

Answer (score 1):

For some reason this worked for me under Big Sur (but not providing the full path to osascript only):

`* * * * * * /usr/bin/bash; osascript -e 'display dialog "Kilroy was here!"'`

Comment: It turned out that prefix command with /bin/zsh; works as well AND EVEN JUST SEMICOLON ;

Comment: `* * * * * * ;osascript -e 'display dialog "Kilroy was here!"'`


This works!

Comment: Final(?) remark: It seems crontab on Mac OS only uses 6 ‘fields’ (with no year). In fact it works in the simplest possible way and I was fooled (next comment for clarity):

Comment: `* * * * * osascript -e 'display dialog "Kilroy was here!"'`

Answer (score 0):

The extra quotes are unnecessary if using crontab. It should work without the quotes. You should be able to confirm this by running in a terminal without Python. If run with the quotes in terminal an error is generated. `bash: osascript -e 'display dialog displaying: command not found`

Try adding this line to your crontab command:

```
osascript -e 'display dialog "displaying content"'
```

Comment: Yes I can directly execute [link](http://example.com) _italic_ **bold** `osascript -e 'display dialog "displaying content"'` in terminal and it works fine. The extra quotes are for python to execute AppleScript, the python code is:[link](http://example.com) _italic_ **bold** `import os
def notify():
    os.system("""
              osascript -e 'display dialog "displaying content" '
              """)
notify()`

Comment: If I execute the above python program in terminal or Pycharm, everything is fine, however if I execute the above program in crontab, the dialog bar would not show.

Comment: You're right, applescript won't run from cron now. You should check this [answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/259039/how-to-run-applescript-in-a-crontab)